# grant in postgresql 9.5 specified for row

Tags: postgresql, row-level-security

I want to add grant with where clause, not for columns, for different users. I'm using this grant update (ename), insert (empno, ename)  on emp to xyz; for catching columns but I can't do this for rows.

Is there any method ?

Answer (score 0):

Just follow this guide : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/ddl-rowsecurity.html
It's pretty straight forward and well documented.

Comment: thanks m8 . I've seen this before but I was not sure .